# git rebase for migrating several commits?

Tags: git

I want to understand a bit more on `git rebase`.

Assume I have this workflow, would `git rebase` be useful here? 
And if so, what would be the command to migrate commits X to Z (assuming not using cherry-pick) from **`MASTER`** to **`BRANCH`**.

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't a merge achieve the same result in this case?

Comment: @nwinkler It doesn't matter whether he merges or rebases from a code functionality point of view.  But he may prefer one over the other from a Git workflow point of view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Believe it or not, you are actually rebasing `master` on `branch` !

Here are the commands you could use to achieve this:

```
git checkout master                  # checkout the master branch
git checkout -b newbranch            # create new branch based on master
git rebase branch                    # rebase on 'branch'
```

Keep in mind I created a new branch called `newbranch` which will appear the way you want it.  It is up to you as to what you want to do with the original `branch`.  Now `newbranch` will look like this:

```
A--B--C--D--X--Y--Z
```

A more typical workflow would be to bring new changes from `master` into `branch` by rebasing the latter on the former, i.e.:

```
git checkout branch
git rebase master
```

This would leave `branch` looking like this:

```
A--X--Y--Z--B--C--D
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. Assume **branch** is threads1, **newbranch** is threads2.
I applied your commands and got the following error - any advice? - sorry I don't know yet how to break the lines in the comment properly.


`$ git checkout master

Already on 'master'

$ git checkout -b threads2

Switched to a new branch 'threads2'

$ git rebase origin threads

fatal: Needed a single revision

invalid upstream origin `

Comment: Sorry threads is threads1 (original branch)>

`$ git rebase origin threads1
fatal: Needed a single revision
invalid upstream origin`

Comment: Thanks Tim. I will confirm your answer soon

Comment: `git rebase origin/branch`

Not sure why, but I needed to add the slash to get it work (otherwise there would be a `fatal: Needed a single revision` error)

Comment: Hi Tim I marked it - thanks. The only thing worth mentioned is that the last command `git rebase origin branch` needs to be changed to `git rebase origin/branch` to work for me. I'm not sure why, please update it you think that is correct.

Comment: Right you are...I removed the reference to `origin`.  Actually, you need to specify the name of a branch.  So `git rebase branch` is OK and `git rebase origin/branch` is also OK.  The former uses the _local_ branch while the latter uses the _remote_.  And `git rebase origin branch` doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

If you do a `git rebase master` (while you have checked out your Branch), you replay the commits of `Branch` *on top of* `master`:

```
A--x--y--z--b'--c'--d' (Branch)
         |
       (master)
```

That is helpful in order to make sure the local commit of your `Branch` are still compatible with the latest evolution from `master`.
Make sure you haven't pushed your `Branch` yet, as it changes its history.

See "[git workflow and rebase vs merge questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/804178/6309)".